# Excel Spreadsheet IF function issue

Tags: function, if-statement, excel-2010

I'm having a problem with an Excel Spreadsheet `IF` function. I'm hoping someone can help fix it. The problem has either been `")"` `"("` or `","` but now it's **"to many arguments"**

```
=IF(C8<=0,0,C8,IF(C8=E7,C8*F6,0,IF(C8=E8,(F7*(C8-(C8*F6))),0,IF(C8=E9,(F8*(C8-(F7*(C8-(C8*F6))))),0,IF(C8>E9,(F9*(C8-(F8*(C8-(F7*(C8-(C8*F6))))))),0,)
```

The spreadsheet function is for Federal taxes if that helps any.

```
C8= original amount
E7= maximum tax bracket amount
F6= percent amount
E8= Next max tax bracket amount
F7= percent amount
E9= Next maximum tax bracket
F8= Percent amount


Federal Tax Rate: single        
Lower   Rate

$0.00       10% 
$9,075.00   15% 
$36,900.00  25% 
$89,350.00  28%
```

Hopefully the edits might help with any answers, I appreciate any effort folks!

The correct result for the If function

```
=IF($C$8<=0,0,IF($C$8=$E$7,$C$8*$F$6,IF($C$8=$E$8,($F$7*($C$8-($C$8*$F$6))),IF($C$8=$E$9,($F$8*($C$8-($F$7*($C$8-($C$8*$F$6))))),IF($C$8>$E$9,($F$9*($C$8-($F$8*($C$8-($F$7*($C$8-($C$8*$F$6))))))),0)))))
```

Comment: Never heard of a "too many arguments" thing in Excel. Generally, it's very stable and it can either work it out or you have done the function wrong. Is this an actual error?

Comment: Yep, that error exists.  "You entered too many arguments for this function. To get help ...."   And yes, he has a problem with the way he is using the function.

Comment: Ok, now give us in words what you want the formula to do.  E.g. If the Original amount is less than 0 then this else that.

Comment: You can't have 3 commas in an "IF" statement.  If you want to nest another "IF" statement within you have to put it into either the "TRUE" or "FALSE" area, not after both (like you've done).

Comment: Very true n8, that's what I was trying to tell him, I'll add that to the answer :-)

Comment: I saw what you were going for, you gave a very complete and accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel the IF function has the format of

```
=IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Looking at your formula

```
=IF(C8<=0,  <--Condition
    0,  <--True
    C8, <--False
    IF( <-- Too many arguments
        C8=E7, <--Condition
        C8*F6, <--True
        0,     <--False
        IF(    <-- Too many arguments
            C8=E8,          <--Condition
            (F7*(C8-(C8*F6)))   <--True
            ,0          <--False
            ,IF(            <-- Too many arguments
                C8=E9,              <--Condition
                (F8*(C8-(F7*(C8-(C8*F6))))),    <--True
                0,              <--False
                IF(             <-- Too many arguments
                    C8>E9,                  <--Condition
                    (F9*(C8-(F8*(C8-(F7*(C8-(C8*F6)))))))   <--True
                    ,0                                      <--False
                    ,                   <--Too many arguments (excess comma)
                )
```

As n8 stated in the comments. You can't have 3 commas in an "IF" statement. If you want to nest another "IF" statement within you have to put it into either the "TRUE" or "FALSE" area, not after both (like you've done)

Maybe you meant

```
=IF
 (
  C8<=0,  <-- logical test
  C8,     <-- value if true
  IF      <-- value if false
```

What you may want to do is give each cell used in the formula a label and then use that label in the formula, and build it up gradually.  Start of with a single if,

```
=IF(OriginalAmount<=0,0,OriginalAmount)
```

That is if OriginalAmount is less than 0 it returns 0, otherwise show the OriginalAmount

Then add a new condition and outcomes, either in the true or false part.

```
=IF(OriginalAmount<=0,0,IF(condition,true,false))
```

Comment: I apologize, could you elaborate? Should the formula wherever there be a 0 be simply an IF?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question.  If C8<=0 what do you want it to be 1) when true, 2) what do you want when false.

Comment: Within the equation I initially wanted the IF statement to read that original number was below zero and it was not possible. Unfortunately I need the Cell to formulate the different adjusted incomes if the number it was referencing was above that.Hence the mess of a formula trying to compute each IF.

Comment: Read my suggested approach in the answer.  I think what you want is possible, you just need to take a step back and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much I ended up correcting the problem guys- =IF($C$8<=0,0,IF($C$8=$E$7,$C$8*$F$6,IF($C$8=$E$8,($F$7*($C$8-($C$8*$F$6))),IF($C$8=$E$9,($F$8*($C$8-($F$7*($C$8-($C$8*$F$6))))),IF($C$8>$E$9,($F$9*($C$8-($F$8*($C$8-($F$7*($C$8-($C$8*$F$6))))))),0)))))